# Computer Keyboard won't work until on-screen keyboard is activated

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 laptop. It happens to be my emergency or last resort laptop. Over the course of one year I have watched some keys on the keyboard stop working. But the moment I turn on my on-screen keyboard they all start functioning well. The problem now is that, even with the on-screen keyboard the keys do not function anymore. So when I turn on the PC i cannot even type in the password. I reached out to Dell customer service but their website says the customer service for that Laptop Model expired already in 2014.

What do I do now? Do I clean the Keys, buy a new keyboard, or is it a driver issue??

Comment: What happens with an external USB keyboard plugged in? If that works, then think about replacing the keyboard, even if it works after login. Also check for malware, e.g., a poorly-written key logger.

Answer (score 0):

First, cleaning the keyboard (carefully) costs nothing, so start with
doing that.

Second, it's unlikely that this is a driver issue.

Third, it's up to you to decide if such an old computer merits a
hardware investment, as more components are probably already in a
fragile state, so replacing them one-by-one until you find the real
problem might be too costly.